# C/pp Sockets, recv()/send() works only under gdb

Tags: c++, c, sockets, debugging

EDIT: In Socket::CanReceive() was logic error. I was checking for input 1 milisecond. That's why while stepping in gdb, everything worked.

I got a problem with the C sockets. `send()`/`recv()` don't do anything if they're in non-debug mode. I can't even `std::cout` their return value. For some reason `std::cout` isn't working in My method. I can't `std::cerr` errno too. There is no point in checking that in gdb, because there everything works perfectly. Wireshark doesn't log packets in non-debug mode.

```
  //b - buffer
  //s - size
  //sd - socket descriptor
  int32_t TCP::Receive(char* b, uint32_t s)
  { Error::Critical.SetErrorNumber(Error::List::NoError);
    if (!Socket::Validate(sd))
    { Error::Critical.SetErrorNumber(Error::List::InvalidSocket);
      return -1;
    }

    if (Disconnected())
    { Error::Critical.SetErrorNumber(Error::List::NotConnected);
      return -1;
    }

    if (!Socket::CanReceive(sd, readTimeout))
     return false;

    if (!b)
    { b = new char [s + 1];
      std::memset(b, '\0', s + 1);
    }

    int32_t bytes = recv(sd, b, s, 0);
    if (bytes == -1)
    { Error::Critical.SetErrorNumber(errno);
      std::cerr << errno << "\n";
      return false;
    }
    std::cout << bytes;
    return bytes;
  }
```

Interesting is fact that gdb without stepping fails too. If I don't set breakpoint in this method, it fails and wireshark nothing log. I thought it could be issue with timings, so server has no time to respond or something, but guess what? `sleep()` doesn't work in both methods.
I don't post `TCP::Send()`, because there is only line of difference.

Comment: Please don't add the word "SOLVED" to your question's title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. If no existing answer is correct (I haven't checked), you can post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not flushing the streams, so you don't see output. Change:

```
  std::cerr << errno << "\n";
```

to

```
  std::cerr << errno << std::endl;
```

and

```
  std::cout << bytes;
```

to

```
std::cout << bytes << std::endl;
```

Comment: I done flushing using std::endl and std::cout.flush(). Both methods don't works. Even if it could work, it still don't explains why sleep() doesn't influence on method.